# Problems with vercel deployment with typescript (NextJS)

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, next.js13, pnpm

I’m having an error on Vercel, during the build it runs on deploy, saying:

[image: Error image on Vercel]

But the same command `pnpm run build` runs smoothly on the PC. Both it and the lint. But still, I went to check the code - but both types here are number:

[image]

[image]

And see that no error is being reported on this line. I even put a parseInt on idValue.

Some things I tried to do:

- I ran the redeploy without the Vercel cache (it gives an option there when we do the redeploy to do it with cache. I just left it unchecked.)
- I cleared the git cache with `git rm -r --cached .`
- I tried to convert the variable to a string just to test. In my local code, it kept saying that the types were incompatible, however, on Vercel it started to report an error in another field with the *same* problem.

I had set up GitHub Actions, but I disabled it because I thought it could be it, but it didn’t work.

I will leave my repo if anyone can help me.
https://github.com/KajiyamaVK/ipve/

The path of the folder is in the error.

**EDIT:**

This is what happens when I remove the parseInt. The component start asking for number as expected.

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Just deleted the node_modules and pnpm install again. All the errors starting appearing to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at your code and you didn't set up the types properly. However, from the screenshot you provided, the prop `id` on the `TableRow` component is expecting a string but you provided it with a number as shown in `line 289`

```
 const idValue = parseInt(row.getValue('id'));
```

Instead of converting `idValue` to a number, leave it as a string, and on line 296, you can convert `idValue` to a number.

Replace `line 288` to `line 312`  with the codeblock below:

```
 table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {
                const idValue: string = row.getValue("id");
                return (
                  <TableRow
                    key={row.id}
                    id={idValue}
                    className="hover:bg-primary-dark hover:text-primary-foreground cursor-pointer "
                    data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                    onClick={() => handleViewState(parseInt(idValue))}
                  >
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => renderTableCell(cell))}
                    <TableCell className="flex gap-2 cursor-pointer">
                      <button
                        aria-label="Deletar"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          e.stopPropagation();
                          handleDelete(parseInt(idValue));
                        }}
                      >
                        <Trash size={24} />
                      </button>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look. That's the problem. If I don't convert to a number on line 289, down below on 296 it will give an error to me LOCALLY only. 
In the image I showed that the component was expecting a number indeed - but I don't know why it asks for a string when building on vercel. 

You solution really works there. But here, as I showed, will start to give an error asking for a number on idValue in TableRow component. 

My code locally is the same as it is on github.

Comment: I edited the issue with the error happening on your solution. Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: I’ve adjusted for line 307. I’ll investigate further for Id type error

Comment: No worries, my man. Just deleted node_modules and pnpm install again. It worked.... idk why I don't do the basic stuff first.... 

THanks a lot, my man.... 
When I re-created node_modules, the errors started appearing for me locally. Sorry to waste your time...

Answer (score 0):

Deleted node_modules and re-created. All the errors starting appearing for me locally.